# Show that an invertible matrix is not nilpotent $(A^{k}=0)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I just need some help if it's correct what I did, this question is asked before we know anything of determinants or anything else really since this is a question in the first chapter of linear algebra.

My answer:

If $A$ is an invertible matrix, then we can write $A$ as the product of elementary matrices $$A=E_{1}\cdot E_{2}\cdot ... \cdot E_{n}$$ So we can consider $A^{k}$ to also be the product of elementary matrices, therefore $A^{k}≠0$, since the product of elementary matrices is not zero.

Could anyone confirm if this is correct, or correct me where I made a mistake

Comment: You don't say anything that isn't true, but why can't a product of elementary matrices be zero?  This proposition [which is true] seems to exist at roughly the same level as the thing you're trying to prove, and hence might also require explanation

Comment: @leslietownes Could it be because an elementary matrix is just the unit matrix with a row modified or switched, therefore it's almost like multiplying by 1?

Comment: This is not enough as a proof.

Answer (score 3):

Let's suppose $A^k=0$ and $A$ is invertible.

Thus $A^{-1}$ exists and $A^{-1}A=I$

Let's do $A^{-1}A^k=A^{k-1}=0$

Rince and repeat.... and you end up with $A=0$

Which is not invertible, thus the initial statement is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to think of it maybe

$$
A^k=0 \implies AA^{k-1} = 0
$$

That means the columns of $A^{k-1}$ belong to the null-space of $A$, which means $A$ has at least one zero eigenvalue, which means it is not invertible.

Answer (score 1):

A proof without determinants is as follows:

Suppose $A^{-1}$ exists and $A^k=0$. Then
$$
I = A^{-1} A=(A^{-1})^2 A^2=\ldots=(A^{-1})^k A^k = (A^{-1})^k 0 = 0,
$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: Next time, don't tell me not to answer very easy questions, please.

Comment: @Piquito I only say don't answer "no effort" questions. But here, I see some effort.

Comment: I respect you and I know that you understand that not knowing a language well (without Google translator, I could not be an MSE contributor) is a very considerable handicap that I must bear personally. I am grateful, however, to MSE for learning to write in English. Greetings.